# Logical correlation from Oedipus myth

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My girlfriend likes the myths and she found an MIT article about Oedipus myth which is looks interesting for her. She showed me, but for me it is looks like no correlation between the logical formulas. Maybe because is it normalized.

If you have time guys, please try to describe me. Which are the correlations between the 2 parts of the formula.

The article is here [article](http://www.academia.edu/312712/From_Determinism_to_Fatalism_and_How_to_Stop_It). The formulas are the following on the second page:

```
    [∃x: outcome x] [∀y: action y] (If Oedipus were to perform y, then x would come about)
    [∀x: actual outcome x] [∀y: possible action y] (If Oedipus were to perform y,
then x would come about)
    [∀x: actual action x] [∀y: possible choice y] (If Oedipus were to make y,
    then Oedipus would perform x)
```

I can't understand how [∃x: outcome x] connected with [∀y: action y].

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The first sentence could be read "No matter what Oedipus does, $x$ is certain to happen." Does this answer your question?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by correlation?

Comment: This probably doesn't address your question, but the second sentence you quoted means "no matter what action Oedipus performs, _every_ outcome will come about", and the third sentence means "no matter what choice Oedipus makes, he will perform _all_ actions".  Those both seem like very strange sentences.

Comment: @TrevorWilson I had the same thought about the second sentence, but there's a difference between "outcome" in the first and "actual outcome" in the second.  The second is saying that every _actual_ outcome occurs for any action that Œdipdus takes;  that is, there is no _actual_ outcome that any of his actions could change.  The unmodified "outcome" in the first might better be phrased "possible outcome".  A similar thing happens in the third  sentence:  no matter which of the _possible_ choices Œdipus makes, he still performs the same _actual_ actions.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys, @AustinMohr can you translate the other 2 formula?

Comment: My first problem with the formulas that are no binding between  [∃x: outcome x] and [∀y: action y]. This is what I mean under correlation. @Trevor Wilson your answer what I am looking for in sentence, but If you could write some formulas what #Joshua writes, that is more perfect :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what your question is.  Where Holton writes

> [∃x: outcome x] [∀y: action y] (If Oedipus were to perform y, then x would come about)

he is expressing something like

$$ \exists x.\left(\mathit{outcome}(x) \land \forall y.( \mathit{action}(y) \to (\mathit{perform}(O,y) > \mathit{happen}(x)) \right)$$

Since Holton's "if … then …" is a [counterfactual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional), I used [the connective $>$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#Connective) instead of the material conditional, $\to$.

By request, here are the other sentences:

> [∀x: actual outcome x] [∀y: possible action y] (If Oedipus were to perform y,
>   then x would come about)

\begin{multline}
\forall{x}.( \mathit{actualOutcome}(x) \to \\
\forall y.(\mathit{possibleAction}(y) \to \\
(\mathit{perform}(O,y) > \mathit{comeAbout}(x))))
\end{multline}

> [∀x: actual action x] [∀y: possible choice y] (If Oedipus were to make y,
>       then Oedipus would perform x)

\begin{multline}
\forall{x}.( \mathit{actualAction}(x) \to \\
\forall y.(\mathit{possibleChoice}(y) \to \\
(\mathit{makeChoice}(O,y) > \mathit{perform}(O,x))))
\end{multline}

Comment: Thank you @Joshia, can you translate the other formulas:) to a formula like this?

Comment: @flatronka They follow pretty much the same pattern:  guarded quantification, then a conterfactual.  I've added them to the answer.